Why is it ok to return a reference to a function's default argument?
#include <iostream>

//class for testing**

class T
{ 
public:
    void print() { std::cout << "hello\n"; }

    ~T() { std::cout << "~T\n";}
};

//function for testing

T& f(T&& obj = T())
{   
    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    f().print(); // outputs first "hello", second "~T"
}

Why does f() not return a dangling reference? The variable is local, as I understand (default var).

"Why is it ok..." It is not. Note that c++ has undefined behavior which means anything can/allowed to happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash. So a program with UB is not ok.

Temporary goes away at end of statement.

@user12002570 there's no UB in this case, f().print() is equivalent to f(T()).print() or just T().print(), if the result of f is stored and used later then there would be UB

@AlanBirtles Yes, the UB related comment was a general advise as OP doesn't look familiar with it.
